# How to check if user is already login in google auth. in android

Tags: java, android

I'm a new android developer and a student. I'm having difficulty of if the user is already login in my app. I will show some of my codes. I greatly appreciate for the help and answer.

Login.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        SignInButton mGoogleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        mGoogleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signInWithGoogle();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
 private void signInWithGoogle(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();

    final Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}



private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if(result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));
        //TODO: Start another explicit intent here. but this time, start MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {

    }
}
```

where did i go wrong ?

Comment: What difficulty exactly? What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: My codes run well, in login part, but when i close my app without logging out, and open again, it still make me direct to login activity, so i want it to direct immediately to mainactivity.

Comment: maintain a boolean isLogin in sharedPreferance, and check it in onCreate() of your activity, if its return true then redirect to your mainActivity.

Answer (score 4):

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient is deprecated now!
So according [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#check_for_an_existing_signed-in_user)

```
   // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
// the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
updateUI(account);
```

For example:

```
 if (GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context) == null) {
            Log.d(TAG_SIGN_FLOW, "User is not signed in, so make login in")

            val signInOptions: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .build()
            startActivityForResult(GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.requireActivity(), signInOptions).signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG_SIGN_FLOW, "User has already been login")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Google Login check whether user is signed in or not:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
   // User is signed in.
   // ...
} else {
   // User is not signed in. 
   // Perform your operation.
}
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient  is deprecated in 2020

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are checking authentication status from any Activity for e.g. Main Activity (Incase fragment get a singleton instance of your context from any activity which it is triggered from).

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            //Todo
        }
    }
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient is deprecated in 2020

Answer (score 0):

To check whether user is logged in and immediately open the MainActivity override the `onStart` method:

```
@Override
 protected void onStart() {
 super.onStart()

 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 FirebaseUser fUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

 if (fUser != null){
  startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Made change in below code-

Maintain a boolean variable in sharedPreferance and will work for you.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin",false))
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        SignInButton mGoogleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        mGoogleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signInWithGoogle();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
 private void signInWithGoogle(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();

    final Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}



private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if(result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));
        //TODO: Start another explicit intent here. but this time, start MainActivity

        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLogin",true).apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i don't know where you get the context, can you please tell me what declaration variable context is ?

Comment: cause my purpose for this is in order for me not to go to login page if the user is already login .

Comment: as you are in activity so no need to take context (updated my answer). 
and i check the condition for isLogin in onCreate of login Activity, if its true then it will finish that and launch MainActivity. it will be to frequent that you will not see loginActivity.

Comment: thank you for the answer but the result is the app suddenly stop. :(

Comment: natsuVsnaruto are you verifying login from Service or Activity? or a Fragment?

Comment: shared pref is a bad solution because your login can be out of date. I mean sign token can become invalid